# How do I fill in the mail verification field?

Tags: laravel

When I register a member at Laravel, I send a confirmation email. But when I click on the verification link, the column in the database does not fill.

*Sample codes:*

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return $user;
}

public function register(Request $request)  {
    $validation = $this->validator($request->all());

    if($request->input('type') == "customer" || $request->input('type') == "company") {
        if ($validation->fails())  {
            return response()->json([$validation->errors()->toArray()], 400);
        }else {
            $this->create($request->all());
        }
    }else {
        return response()->json([
            0 => ['Üyelik sırasında bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.']
        ], 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you follow the instructions given in official laravel documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification

Comment: @Theekshana Yes.

Comment: @Dodiş. Add your `User model` as well.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada everything is right. It works when there is no register function. The column does not fill when I register via the register function.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you migrated the tables after running the auth boilerplate?
2) Have you checked your logs for any additional errors that might be showing?

Comment: No log today my friend